# GHC fails to load fftw bindings, what's it's issue?

Tags: haskell, linker, ghc, fftw

I'm trying to use the fftw haskell bindings in Math.FFT. When attempting to compile ghc spits out the following

: /usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a: Bad magic. Expected: feedface, got: feedfacf.

ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 7.4.1 for i386-apple-darwin):
    loadArchive "/usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a": failed

Please report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug

I've reinstalled fftw3 but no change, any suggestions on what the problem could be?

Comment: did you install GHC from source? i would recommend using mac ports and installing GHC and fftw3 from there

Comment: Looks like ghc is 32 bit, and /usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a is 64 bit. feedface is macho 32 bit magic, and feedfacf is the macho 64 bit magic.

Answer (score 1):

Bad magic means the object file is corrupted, or in the wrong format for your machine.

Since you are on i386-darwin, and attempting to link, it suggests that your .a or .o or .so files are the wrong ones for your architecture.